# Why do some pages on my site use the previous theme?

Tags: page-template, child-theme

I have developed a WordPress website using a Child Theme, I started with Twenty Ten as the base, then I created a new and improved version with Twenty Eleven as the base and some new features, now I have done it again with Twenty Twelve as the Parent theme.

The new features are working mostly great, except when viewing certain pages on the site it wants load the Stylesheet, etc. from the previous (Differently named, Twenty Eleven child) theme. Why?

URL: http://winemerchantltd.com/
Observe the home page (header, menu, sidebar, etc), then click on the "CLASSES" or "FIND WINE" link to see what I am talking about.

Thank You

Comment: Disable all plugins, and clean up .htaccess rules for caching plugins. Does it still happen?

Comment: old .htaccess rules from W3T-cache plugin, works again thank you :)

Comment: you should answer though, so I can vote it up.  I would give you a "useful comment" but I can't see how.  I guess cause this is my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During development disable all caching. Short check list:

- no caching plugins active
- no caching rules in .htaccess
- [add a time stamp to your theme stylesheets](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40667/how-do-you-avoid-caching-during-development/40669#40669)
- [add a time stamp to editor stylesheets](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33318/forcing-reload-of-editor-style-css/59196#59196)